# Find Documents by the number of embedded array elements that match condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and need help in accomplishing my task:

I am using MongoDB to query for actions that were taken by a person. The actions are embedded in the person document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56447ac0583d4871570041c3"),
    "email" : "email@example.net",
    "actions" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "support",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-17T01:40:35.000Z"),
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "hide",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-16T01:40:35.000Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "support",
            "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-17T03:40:35.000Z"),
        }
    ]
}
```

A person can have many actions with different action names (`support` and `hide` are just 2 examples).

I know that I could find all people with at least one `support` action like this:

```
db.test.find({'actions.name':'support'})
```

What I want to do, is, retrieve all people with at least X `support` actions. Is this possible without using javascript syntax? As people could have hundreds of actions, this would be slow.

So, If I want all people with at least 2 `support` actions, the only way I know would be using the js syntax:

```
db.test.find({$where: function() {
  return this.actions.filter(function(action){
    return action.name = 'support';
  }).length >= 2;
}});
```

Is there an other/better/faster possibility for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the best way to do this is using the the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access  to the aggregation pipelines.

You can reduce the  size of documents to process on the pipeline using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator to filter out all documents that don't match the given criteria.

You need to use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) operator to return only documents where the numbers of elements that with name "support" in your array is [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/#exp._S_gte) `2`. The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator here return an array of subdocuments that match your critera and false that you can easily drop using the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) operator. Of course the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) operator returns the size of the array.

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "actions.name": "support", 
        "actions.2": { "$exists": true } 
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$gte": [
                { "$size": { 
                    "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": { 
                            "input": "$actions", 
                            "as": "action", 
                            "in": { 
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$action.name", "support" ] }, 
                                    "$$action", 
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }}, 
                        [false]
                     ]
                }}, 
                2
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

From MongoDB 3.2 this can be handled using the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_filter) operator.

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "actions.name": "support", 
        "actions.2": { "$exists": true } 
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$gte": [
                { "$size": { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$actions", 
                        "as": "action", 
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$action.name", "support" ] }
                    }
                }}, 
                2
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

As @BlakesSeven pointed out:

> `$setDifference` is fine as long as the data being filtered is "unique". In this case it "should" be fine, but if any two results contained the same date then it would skew results by considering the two to be one. `$filter` is the better option when it comes, but if data was not unique it would be necessary to $unwind at present.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't benchmarked this against your attempt, but this sounds like a great usecase for Mongo's aggregation framework.

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$actions"},
{$group: { 
  _id: { _id: "$_id", action: "$actions},
  count: {$sum: 1}
},
{$match: {$and: [{count: {$gt: 2}}, {"_id.action": "support"]}
]);
```

Note that I havent run this in mongo, so it might have some syntax issues.

The idea behind it is:

1. `unwind` the actions array so each element of the array becomes its own document
2. `group` the resulting collection by an _id - action type pair, and count how much we get of each.
3. `match` will filter for only things we are interested in.

Comment: No this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @user3100115 Why do you think its not what the OP wants?

Comment: run his query and compare the result to yours then you will understand "why". Also the question is very clear

Comment: @user3100115 Im not on a computer with Mongo right now, but I agree his question is clear... and from what I can tell I've clearly answered his question of finding all people with with more than X support actions.

Comment: He wants to return all documents that match the given criteria not subdocuments

Comment: @user3100115 I'm returning him the IDs of all the documents that match. If he wants more info he can project more fields in the `$group`. This answers his question.

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's question which is the "filtered count matching support" or in fact "having array members containing support more than twice". The code here just counts members in the array, including other values than "support" in the array content. The `$size` operator alone can count the array members, which is all this is doing.